# SQL Query to provide me with the total number

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table with 3 columns

```
Column 0: auto inc index
Column 1: Person's Gener
Column 2: The STATE the person lives in (US States and Puerto Rico)
```

I want to run a query that tells me how many MEN are in each state
so the output would list all 50 states (in 1 column) and the second would be a number to determine the number of MEN in that state

```
Alaska 1000
New York 85000
```

(the figures above aren't accurate but i'm illustrating what I am looking for)

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? To provide you with a hint, it's got something to do with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select STATE, count(*) as num from table_name where gender ='MALE' GROUP BY STATE;
```

Comment: Does not take the gender into account.

Comment: yeah.. had in mind but missed to type because of hurry to answer on SOF :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a GROUP BY clause and the [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) aggregate function.

```
SELECT State, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfMen
FROM your_table
WHERE Gender = 'M'
GROUP BY State
```